# Making custom android views "tappable" with a feedback highlight

Tags: android, user-interface, view, highlight

I'm using a custom view expanded from a XML layout in a horizontal scroll view as a sort of horizontal image list but I'm not sure how to get them to appear clickable/tappable (ie they highlight when tapped) or how to capture these events. I think I've tried setOnClickHandler without it working. I'm also trying to get a simple TextView to do the same. I've also tried setting android:clickable="true" but that hasn't helped either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To take care of the visual feedback use an [xml Selector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList), and set it as the View's background.

To handle click events use

```
mView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //your code here
    }
});
```